# A call to an async function is not awaited. Use the "await" keyword in Test Cafe

Tags: testing, automation, testcafe

I'm getting this error:

A call to an async function is not awaited. Use the "await" keyword
before actions, assertions or chains of them to ensure that they run
in the right sequence.

But I am using an await within my code, what am I doing incorrectly?

```
test("Accepts the cookie", async t => {

    const interfaceSelect = Selector('#sp_message_iframe_617100');
    await
        t.switchToIframe('#sp_message_iframe_617100')
        t.click(Selector('button').withText('Accept'))
        t.switchToIframe('#select_region-select-module_select_30IZf')
        const countrySelect = Selector('#region-select-module_select__30lZf');
        t.click(Selector('button').withText('United Kingdom'))
});
```

Thanks,

Comment: You have several actions here: 1. `t.switchToIframe('#sp_message_iframe_617100')`, 2. `t.click(Selector('button').withText('Accept'))`, 3. `t.switchToIframe('#select_region-select-module_select_30IZf')`, 4. `t.click(Selector('button').withText('United Kingdom'))`. You should use `await` before each of them

Answer (score 0):

The TestCafe's methods are chainable and return a Promise.
You need to add an `await` before each method call or one `await` before the whole chain.

```js
test("Accepts the cookie", async t => {

    const interfaceSelect = Selector('#sp_message_iframe_617100');

    await t.switchToIframe('#sp_message_iframe_617100');
    await t.click(Selector('button').withText('Accept'));
    await t.switchToIframe('#select_region-select-module_select_30IZf');

    const countrySelect = Selector('#region-select-module_select__30lZf');

    await t.click(Selector('button').withText('United Kingdom'));
});
```

```js
test("Accepts the cookie", async t => {
    const interfaceSelect = Selector('#sp_message_iframe_617100');

    await t
        .switchToIframe('#sp_message_iframe_617100')
        .click(Selector('button').withText('Accept'))
        .switchToIframe('#select_region-select-module_select_30IZf');

    const countrySelect = Selector('#region-select-module_select__30lZf');

    await  t.click(Selector('button').withText('United Kingdom'));
});
```